# How to find/highlight a word in the current line only

Tags: vimscript, search

As title. The current problem is that my window is scrolled to the first/next(?) global occurrence. But I just want it to move my cursor to the local one, i.e. the current line, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\%l` atom to restrict the search to the current cursor line, so in your case you probably want `/<regex>\%.l`

The `.` before the `l` is the shortcut to only search in the cursor line. See [:h /%l](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25l)

Comment: This gets rid of the visual mode, which is great and better!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this can fit my requirement:

```lua
vim.cmd("exe 'normal! V'")
vim.cmd("/\\%V"..input)
```